# Cannot find module './_apply'

Tags: node.js, module, ghost

If I run

```
node index
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Cannot find module './_apply'
```

I used npm install, and tried to manually install it

which node returns:

```
/usr/bin/node
```

which npm returns:

```
/usr/bin/npm
```

and echo $NODE_PATH

```
/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
```

Apply is in node_modules, so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I had a few other modules to install, and they worked normally with  npm install.

Answer (score 3):

Removed the node_modules folder, cleared the cache, and redid everything. It worked. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you "npm install apply" and did you try doing require("apply")?

Comment: Yeah, I did both of those.